# Laravel 5.4 $.post() jquery.min.js:4 POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

This is my first time using jquery post function in laravel. I am using laravel 5.4. i want to submit data via jquery.

Here's my blade template view:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('doctor.register') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <a href="#" id="ajaxclick">On click ajax</a>
</form>
</body>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/ajax', 'TestController@ajax')->name('test.ajax');
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#ajaxclick" ).click(function() {
        var token = $("#token").val();
        var identity = 5;
        $.post( "/ajax", { id: identity, token: token },
            function( data ) {
                console.log( "ajax working"); 
                console.log( data.id );
            }, "json");

    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request['id'];
    $id = $id + 1;
    return response()->json(array('success'=>true, 'id'=>$id));
}
```

But when i click on  tag it gives me 500 (Internal Server Error) in console log.
[image]

Now, how can i pass data via post function ? Any help ?

Comment: Open and read error logs.

Comment: `'id'=>id` should be `'id'=>$id`

Comment: As indicated by "Internal Server Error", there's a server (probably PHP) error occurring when it tries to respond to your ajax request. Ensure your server has error reporting and logging turned on, and check what the actual error is. Then it'll be much easier to find and fix. But as mulder says, you have an obvious syntax error. Maybe that's the only problem, maybe not. The logs will tell you.

Comment: @u_mulder I didn't read error logs before in laravel. Can you tell me how can i read my error logs in laravel ?

Comment: @NazemMahmud search engines are your friend: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=laravel+error+log+location&oq=laravel+error+log&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7109j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . But before you spend time on that, do what mulder suggested and see if that fixes it.

Comment: i did what mulder said . Now i am trying to find error in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file. But still can't find specific error for `internal server error` @ADyson

Comment: Ok so am I to understand you are still getting the error after that change? Anyway, it won't say "internal server error" in your logs - that's just what the webserver says to the client, to avoid giving away any info about the server structure (for security). Instead match items in your logs to the error based on the time it happened. It should hopefully have a more descriptive error message, possibly with line number, function name etc etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved::**
I have edited my JS file like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#ajaxclick" ).click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var token = $("#token").val();
        var identity = 5;
        $.post( "/ajax", { id: identity, token: token },
            function( data ) {
                console.log( "ajax working"); 
                console.log( data.id );
            }, "json");
    });
});
```